# What does the neqany() command do in Stata?

Tags: php, stata

I've come across a Stata command `neqany(a, b, c)`. The a, b & c = a numeric variable. The code is to help calculate EQ5D values.

More specifically, the code is as follows:

```
egen i1 = neqany(m0 s0 u0 p0 a0), values(1)
```

I don't know what the `neqany(a, b, c)` and the `values(1)` part of the code is meant to do. In the long run, I am trying to translate it to php code.

In addition, does anyone have a translated version of the EQ5D value set calculations in php?

Comment: Corrected typos. Your code is right: the function is `neqany()`. If as your title and text originally had it, you were searching for `negany()` you would I suspect have found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what EQ5D means, but as your code shows `neqany()` is an `egen` function in Stata, not a command.

Looking at the source code (which requires knowing that `egen` functions all are defined by programs with names starting `_g` (which in turn is shown by looking at the `egen` source code (but this is a programming forum and looking at the code is what we do))) with

```
viewsource _gneqany.ado
```

tells the story:

```
*! version 8.0.0  04oct2004
program define _gneqany
        // -egen- function -neqany()- renamed to -anycount()- for Stata 9

        // no -version #- statement
        _ganycount `0'
end
```

Hence look at the documentation of `anycount()` in `egen` help or manual entries, e.g. http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?egen

Comment: Brilliant thanks! I think I got stumped with the "neqany" and thought it had something to do with looking for negative numbers. Thats probably how the typo got in there. Should've been more explicit, the EQ5D is the euro-qol (quality of life questionnaire), for which there is stata code that was published and had the old code from prior to Stata 9. Thanks, this allows me to try and translate to php (if its possible).

Comment: Bizarrely, the name was originally given by me to a function I wrote which was later folded into Stata. It was intended to be parsed as `n`umber `eq`ual to `any`. Originally, I think someone mentioned a SAS function with some similar name, but this was about 20 years ago. At that time, Stata program names were subject to a filename.ext or 8.3 name length because Stata was subject to DOS filename restrictions. Given `_g` as the first two characters, the rest of the name could be at most 6 characters long. When that restriction no longer bit, the longer name `anycount()` became possible.

Comment: Interesting to hear about nomenclature changes due to the DOS legacy. I got in to Stata at the release of Stata 11, so may not have been exposed to many parsed function names. I wonder if "twoway" and the "oneway" commands while intuitive, were named that way due to DOS restrictions.

Comment: No, I don't think so; they are just simple short names. They weren't chosen because longer names were out of order.